# How to require Mongoid without affecting ActiveRecord migrations

Tags: mongoid

I have a Rails application that has many ActiveRecord models

we recently introduce Mongoid so that some model data may be stored in Mongo

Mongoid automatically took over migrations & generators

is there way how to require `mongoid` such that it will not override rails defaults?

---

from [Mongoid and ActiveRecord generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404001/mongoid-and-activerecord-generators)  I can see that I can do

```
# config/application.rb
config.generators.orm :active_record
```

but migrations seems to be still affected

Answer (score 0):

hmm, seems that I need to require again AR railtie with:

```
# config/application.rb
require "active_record/railtie"

config.generators do |g|
  g.orm :active_record
end
```

- source [How can I do "rake db:migrate" with mongoid and active record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35077815/how-can-i-do-rake-dbmigrate-with-mongoid-and-active-record)

this works but it feels counter intuitive. I should be able to tell mongoid not to include everything rather than  re-overiding mongoid railtie (that is overiding AR railty) by requiring AR railty

any better idea out there ?